# gedit: how to increase spaces between lines?

Tags: gedit

I am using gedit with a strange font that the lines sometimes overwrite on each other.
can I change the spacing between lines?

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: how can I instert it please ?

Comment: @gRoMBi Upload [here](http://www.imgur.com/) and then post the direct link into your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The External Tools plugin can help change the spacing between lines.

Specifically, it extends gedit by helping you to run scripts on your working files, and by allowing gedit to interact with other programs on your computer.

To enable the External Tools plugin, select:

Gedit ---- Preferences ---- Plugins ---- External Tools.

Once you have enabled the plugin, you will need to configure it to suit your needs.

The configuration options are available by selecting:

Tools ---- Manage External Tools.

Requires knowledge of scripting to be used effectively.

A dialog will appear and you can start adding tools.

To run tools, go to:

Tools ---- External Tools or use if applicable associated shortcut keys.

Storage and hand-editing of tools: /usr/share/gedit/plugins/externaltools/tools.

An example of LineSpacing plugin for Gedit in:

http://natural966.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/my-linespacing-plugin-for-gedit-3/

And consists of two files:

linespacing.plugin:

```
[Plugin]
Loader=python
Module=linespacing
IAge=3
Name=Line-spacing
Description=Increase or decrease space between lines
Authors=
Copyright=
Website=
```

linespacing.py:

```
from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk, Gedit

UI_XML = """<ui>
<menubar name="MenuBar">
    <menu name="ToolsMenu" action="Tools">
      <placeholder name="ToolsOps_3">
        <menuitem name="LineSpacingAction0" action="LineSpacingAction0"/>
        <menuitem name="LineSpacingAction1" action="LineSpacingAction1"/>
        <menuitem name="LineSpacingAction2" action="LineSpacingAction2"/>
      </placeholder>
    </menu>
</menubar>
</ui>"""

class LineSpacing(GObject.Object, Gedit.WindowActivatable):
    __gtype_name__ = "LineSpacing"
    window = GObject.property(type=Gedit.Window)

    def __init__(self):
        GObject.Object.__init__(self)

    def _add_ui(self):
        manager = self.window.get_ui_manager()
        self._actions = Gtk.ActionGroup("LineSpacingActions")
        self._actions.add_actions([
            ('LineSpacingAction0', Gtk.STOCK_INFO, "Reset Line spacing", 
                "<Control><Alt>0", "Reset Line spacing", 
                self.on_linespacing_action_activate0),
            ('LineSpacingAction1', Gtk.STOCK_INFO, "Decrease Line spacing", 
                "<Control><Alt>8", "Decrease Line spacing", 
                self.on_linespacing_action_activate1),
            ('LineSpacingAction2', Gtk.STOCK_INFO, "Increase Line spacing", 
                "<Control><Alt>9", "Increase Line spacing", 
                self.on_linespacing_action_activate2),
        ])
        manager.insert_action_group(self._actions)
        self._ui_merge_id = manager.add_ui_from_string(UI_XML)
        manager.ensure_update()

    def do_activate(self):
        self._add_ui()

    def do_deactivate(self):
        self._remove_ui()

    def do_update_state(self):
        pass

    def on_linespacing_action_activate0(self, action, data=None):
        view = self.window.get_active_view()
        if view:
            view.set_pixels_below_lines(0)
            view.set_pixels_inside_wrap(0)

    def on_linespacing_action_activate1(self, action, data=None):
        view = self.window.get_active_view()
        if view:
            if view.get_pixels_below_lines() >= 0:
                view.set_pixels_below_lines(view.get_pixels_below_lines() - 1)
            if view.get_pixels_inside_wrap() >= 0:
                view.set_pixels_inside_wrap(view.get_pixels_inside_wrap() - 1)

    def on_linespacing_action_activate2(self, action, data=None):
        view = self.window.get_active_view()
        if view:
            view.set_pixels_below_lines(view.get_pixels_below_lines() + 1)
            view.set_pixels_inside_wrap(view.get_pixels_inside_wrap() + 1)

    def _remove_ui(self):
        manager = self.window.get_ui_manager()
        manager.remove_ui(self._ui_merge_id)
        manager.remove_action_group(self._actions)
        manager.ensure_update()
```

Sources:

```
http://natural966.wordpress.com/2012/08/19/my-linespacing-plugin-for-gedit-3/

http://www.micahcarrick.com/writing-plugins-for-gedit-3-in-python.html

https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Gedit3PluginSample
```

Comment: The latest version of gedit only support python3 in plugins so you have to change 'Loader' in 'linespacing.plugin' to 'python3', just add a 3 at the end to indicate that this plugin is to be run using python3. And of course you need to have python3 installed on your system (it can be installed concurrently to python2 and doesn't need to be the deafult).

Comment: I didn't need to mess around with Manage External Tools. I just added the above couple of files to `~/.local/share/gedit/plugins` and restarted `gedit`.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a small plugin for line spaceing for gedit 3

[gedit-plugin-linespaces](https://github.com/hamadmarri/gedit-plugin-linespaces)

download 'linespaces.plugin' and 'linespaces.py', and move them to '~/.local/share/gedit/plugins/'

set 'pixels' in 'linespaces.py'

run `gedit` go to preferences -> plugins -> select Line Spacing